# How to calculate Inverse Fourier Transform and cancel out things like HeavisideTheta (so, the function looks exactly like the initial notation)

Tags: fourier-analysis

my question has two parts (please check everything for any mistakes):

The Fourier transform of

```
FourierTransform[Exp[-a Abs[t]], t, ω, 
 FourierParameters -> {1, -1}]=(2 a)/(a^2 + ω^2)
```

which is the correct answer.

1.How to get its Inverse Fourier Transform correctly?

```
InverseFourierTransform[2 a/((a^2) + (ω^2)), ω, t, 
 Assumptions -> a > 0 , FourierParameters -> {1, -1}]=E^(a t) HeavisideTheta[-t] + E^(-a t) HeavisideTheta[t]
```

is it correct?

2. How to display the Inverse Fourier Transform  without any  `HeavisideTheta`?(or anything else which makes the answer different from the initial function) so the answer looks like the initial theoretical notation: Exp[-a Abs[t]].

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

```
$Version

"12.1.0 for Mac OS X x86 (64-bit) (March 14, 2020)"

Clear["Global`*"]

expr = Exp[-a Abs[t]];

ft = FourierTransform[expr, t, ω, FourierParameters -> {1, -1}]

(* (2 a)/(a^2 + ω^2) *)

ift[t_] = InverseFourierTransform[ft, ω, t, Assumptions -> a > 0,
  FourierParameters -> {1, -1}]

(* E^(a t) HeavisideTheta[-t] + E^(-a t) HeavisideTheta[t] *)
```

Since [`HeavisideTheta`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/HeavisideTheta.html) is undefined at zero, the `ift` is equal  to `expr` everywhere except for `t == 0`.

```
Simplify[expr == ift[t], #] & /@ {t < 0, t == 0, t > 0}

(* {True, 2 HeavisideTheta[0] == 1, True} *)
```

This is due to the fact that `expr` is not smooth for `t == 0`

```
Plot[expr /. a -> 1, {t, -3, 3}]
```

[image]

**EDIT:** For `FourierParameters -> {1, -1}]` the `InverseFourierTransform` is given by

```
ift[t_] = 1/(2 Pi) Integrate[
   ft E^(I ω t), {ω, -Infinity, Infinity},
   Assumptions -> {a > 0, Element[t, Reals]}]

(* E^(-a Abs[t]) *)

ift[t] == expr

(* True *)
```

Comment: what should I add to the `InverseFourierTransform`  to not calculate for t=0?

Comment: `InverseFourierTransform` does not calculate the inverse for `t == 0` since the inverse is not defined there.  If you want to define `ift` at zero, use `Limit`, i.e.,  `ift[0] = Limit[ift[t], t -> 0]`

Comment: Yeah, I got that part, but please just mention this how can I recreate the exact initial function `Exp[-a Abs[t]]` ?